# Concatenate duplicate dataframe values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a very long dataframe where 1 column out of nearly 56 has many different values, while the rest of the data change in accordance with the first column ID. Here's an example

```
ID  chrom   left    right   ref_seq var_type    zygosity    transcript_name
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a       SNP         Hom         NM_033486
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a       SNP         Hom         NM_033487
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a       SNP         Hom         NM_033488
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a       SNP         Hom         NM_033489
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a       SNP         Hom         NM_033492
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a       SNP         Hom         NM_033493
1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g       SNP         Hom         NM_033486
1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g       SNP         Hom         NM_033487
1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g       SNP         Hom         NM_033488
1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g       SNP         Hom         NM_033489
1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g       SNP         Hom         NM_033492
```

The desired result would be to concatenate any duplicate values into a comma seperated string but maintain the ID only once, like this

```
ID  chrom   left    right   ref_seq var_type    zygosity    transcript_name
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a       SNP         Hom         NM_033486NM_033487,NM_033488,NM_033489,NM_033492,NM_033493
1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g       SNP         Hom         NM_033486,NM_033487,NM_033488,NM_033489,NM_033492
```

I've searched for similar questions and [the following solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262741/combining-duplicated-rows-in-r-and-adding-new-column-containing-ids-of-duplicate) haven't worked so far; instead they return me a zero row dataframe.

Comment: Why do you get all 0? Can you show your script that doesn't work?

Comment: The following code worked for me, assuming your working data frame is the same as provided.   `df2 <- aggregate(df[,8], df[,-8], 
                 FUN = function(X) paste(unique(X), collapse=", "))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
#setDT will convert the data.frame into data.table
#.SD gives you access to the groups of data.tables created by the 'by' argument
setDT(df)[, list(transcript_name = paste(transcript_name, collapse = ', ')), 
            by = c('ID', 'chrom', 'left', 'right', 'ref_seq', 'var_type', 'zygosity')]
#   ID chrom    left   right ref_seq var_type zygosity                                                  transcript_name
#1:  0  chr1 1590327 1590328       a      SNP      Hom NM_033486, NM_033487, NM_033488, NM_033489, NM_033492, NM_033493
#2:  1  chr1 1590526 1590527       g      SNP      Hom            NM_033486, NM_033487, NM_033488, NM_033489, NM_033492
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'ID  chrom   left    right   ref_seq var_type    zygosity    transcript_name
0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a   SNP Hom NM_033486
                 0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a   SNP Hom NM_033487
                 0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a   SNP Hom NM_033488
                 0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a   SNP Hom NM_033489
                 0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a   SNP Hom NM_033492
                 0   chr1    1590327 1590328 a   SNP Hom NM_033493
                 1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g   SNP Hom NM_033486
                 1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g   SNP Hom NM_033487
                 1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g   SNP Hom NM_033488
                 1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g   SNP Hom NM_033489
                 1   chr1    1590526 1590527 g   SNP Hom NM_033492')
```

Comment: Yeah right! It is my usual way of over-complicating things :P. Thanks for the comment /  edit guys. @docendodiscimus

Answer (score 8):

Another solution using base R

```
aggregate(data=df,transcript_name~.,FUN=paste,collapse=",")
```

Thanks to @Sotos & @LyzandeR for `collapse`

Comment: You also need to `collapse`

Comment: @user2100721 use `str(aggregate(data=df,transcript_name~.,FUN=paste))` and you ll see the difference

Comment: or better yet, save both versions `df1 <- aggregate(...paste)` and `df2 <- aggregate(...paste, collapse = ',')` and `View` the results

Comment: You could just use `toString` instead

Comment: @LyzandeR & Sotos Ok. I got that. Thanks.

Comment: I get the following message "Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate"

Comment: This is weird. Does anyone have any idea?