# Consolidating duplicate rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

This is a continuation of a past question I asked. Basically, I have a dataframe, `df`

```
         Beginning1 Protein2    Protein3    Protein4    Biomarker1
Pathway3    A         G           NA           NA           F
Pathway6    A         G           NA           NA           E
Pathway2    A         B           H            NA           F
Pathway5    A         B           H            NA           E
Pathway1    A         D           K            NA           F
Pathway7    A         B           C            D            F
Pathway4    A         B           C            D            E
```

And now I want to consolidate the rows to look like this:

```
dfnew 
         Beginning1 Protein2    Protein3    Protein4    Biomarker1
Pathway3    A         G           NA           NA           F, E
Pathway2    A         B           H            NA           F, E
Pathway7    A         D           K            NA           F    
Pathway1    A         B           C            D            F, E
```

I've seen a lot of people consolidate identical rows in dataframes using aggregate, but I can't seem to get that function to work on non-numerical values.  The closest question I have seen solved it like this: `df1 <- aggregate(df[7], df[-7], unique)` and can be found here: [Combining duplicated rows in R and adding new column containing IDs of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262741/combining-duplicated-rows-in-r-and-adding-new-column-containing-ids-of-duplicate).

Also, not every pathway has a matching pair, as can be seen in pathway 1.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Could you explain in words how you are combining them? Are you just taking every pair of rows and then pasting together Biomarker1?

Comment: Also, it appears you have a column named `1`, which is not a valid variable name in a data frame.

Comment: No, its not just every pair of rows.  It is only the rows that are identical from Protein 2 to Protein4.  I just added in another hypothetical pathway, to show that not all pathways have a matching pair.

Comment: OK, please edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution using the ‹dplyr› and ‹tidyr› packages should do what you want:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Protein2, Protein3, Protein4) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(Biomarker1 = lapply(data, `[[`, 'Biomarker1'),
           Biomarker1 = unlist(lapply(Biomarker1, paste, collapse = ', '))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # Restore the “Beginning1” column is a bit of work, unfortunately.
    mutate(Beginning1 = lapply(data, `[[`, 'Beginning1'),
           Beginning1 = unlist(lapply(Beginning1, `[[`, 1))) %>%
    select(-data)
```

Comment: is the nest function in a specific package?

Comment: @TaylorMaurer Yes, as mentioned in my answer. Though see update. I made a mistake.

Comment: nest() appears to be in the package tidyr, but when ever I try to run the function, I get this error: Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "nest"

Comment: I am having issues using this with a larger dataframe that contains 14 proteins (and matches identical pathways from Protein2:Protein14).  Could you explain your code a little bit so I can modify it for this new dataset?

Comment: @TaylorMaurer To modify this code for 14 proteins, you need to modify the `group_by` call and replace it with `group_by_(paste0('Protein', 2 : 14))`. However, at this point you should reconsider your data format: instead of having 14 protein columns you should probably transform your table into [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), with one single column for the protein number and one for its amino acid (?). This will lead to a complete rewrite of the code though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dplyr solution which should yield the expected result.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
      group_by(Beginning1, Protein2, Protein3, Protein4) %>%
      summarise(Biomarker1 = paste(Biomarker1, collapse = ", "))
```

Comment: When I try to run either your code or the code by @KonradRudolph on a much large dataset, I keep getting this error:                                           Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, key_col, value = list(list(Beginning1 = c(1L,  : replacement has 7 rows, data has 97

Comment: Do either of you know what this means or how I can fix this error?